# Magento accessing a database located in mssql server 2008

Tags: magento

I need to access tables in another database which is in mssql server 2008.
I need to access this database using my magento module. just for test whether i can connect to the database, i tried below code in test.php file.

```
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "your_name";
$myPass = "your_password";
$myDB = "examples";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

But i am getting below error;
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thank You so much.

Comment: you can connect with [this method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php). Hope it is solve your problem

Comment: If you are using PHP 7.0 mssql_connect function has been removed.

Comment: thank for helping. I used sqlsrv_connect method also. But not working :(

Comment: is extension=php_mssql.dll is enabled in php ?